# How to prevent this query from printing same results twice?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, repeat

I managed to create a query that fit my need.  But now I am running into issues where given the current way of displaying results the query repeats each and every result twice.  How can i make it work correctly where it shows it once.

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT contacts.contact_id, user_accounts.full_name, 
contact_notes.note_name, contact_notes.type, contact_notes.note_id, 
contact_posts.why_post, contact_posts.type, contact_posts.post_id
FROM contacts, user_accounts, contact_notes, contact_posts
WHERE (contacts.system_id = '$sid' AND contacts.contact_id = 
user_accounts.system_id AND contact_notes.user_allowed = '$everybody' AND   
contact_posts.user_allowed = '$everybody') OR (contacts.contact_id = '$sid' 
AND contacts.system_id = user_accounts.system_id AND contact_notes.user_allowed 
= '$everybody' AND contact_posts.user_allowed = '$everybody')
LIMIT $startrow, 20";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$noteid = htmlspecialchars($row['note_id']);
$note_title = htmlspecialchars($row['note_name']);
$postid = htmlspecialchars($row['post_id']);
$postreason = htmlspecialchars($row['why_post']);
$datetimeadded = htmlspecialchars($row['just_date']);

print("<br /> <br />$note_title - $noteid <br /><br />$postreason - $postid");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mysql_fetch_array()` use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). By default, `mysql_fetch_array()` will return an array with both associative *and* number indices which will result in you seeing the results twice.

Comment: Hey, that still repeats the queries twice.

Comment: Hey, i still need some help.  With mysql_fetch_assoc() i am getting the same issue.